# Center align content in Angular material is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using **Angular 8** and **Angular Material** for layout.

I have a `card` with `progress spinner`

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content class="text-center">
    <mat-progress-spinner class="text-center"
      [color]="color"
      [mode]="mode">
    </mat-progress-spinner>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[image]

It is aligned on the `left`. I want to align `center`.

I tried adding `text-center` with CSS

```
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

But this does not work. Isn't there any predefined `class` for aligning content in the Angular Material?

I found one on Google search: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment, But this is form `Angularjs` version.

Comment: Try `.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}`

Comment: Isn't there predefined classes for that like bootstrap or Angularjs material?

Comment: @AliWahab `!important` has no effect.

Comment: I am sure its doable. Can you please create a stackBlitz example?

Comment: `<mat-card class="w-100-p"></mat-card>

.w-100-p{
width: 100%
}

if display: flex then put 

display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it whit flex, adding  this css in your component:

```
mat-card-content {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

Use normal css, Add margin: 0 auto to the mat-progress-spinner tag.

It worked for me.

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-progress-spinner style="margin: 0 auto;"
      [color]="color"
      [mode]="mode">
    </mat-progress-spinner>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this small hack. It works in fine in stackBlitz

```
<mat-card>
  <div align="center">
 <mat-card-content >
    <mat-progress-spinner
      [color]="color"
      [mode]="mode">
    </mat-progress-spinner>
  </mat-card-content>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```